# Typescript Joi date validation

Tags: typescript, joi

Is there any way to make Joi.date only accept YYYY-MM-DD format?
I tried to use:

```
Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

but I get an error

```
Property 'format' does not exist on type 'DateSchema'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Did you forget to add joi-date? https://joi.dev/module/joi-date/

Comment: @jonrsharpe if i add joi-date and send the date like i want, ex: "1984-02-01", it returns Error: Unknown date format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: i found the error .. the error was the way i was extending joi-date from joi in the import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you install both `joi` and `@joi/date` and extend `Joi` as shown below.

```
const Joi = require('joi')
.extend(require('@joi/date'));
```

Then you should be able to use `Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` without any error.

Comment: how can I extend if I'm using import?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `import` instead of `require()` then use the following code.

```
import coreJoi from "joi";
import joiDate from "@joi/date";
const joi = coreJoi.extend(joiDate) as typeof coreJoi;

const sampleEntry = joi.object({
    fromDate: joi.date().format("YYYY-MM-DD").required(),
    toDate: joi.date().format("YYYY-MM-DD").required(),
});
```

Alternately you can also write the `imports` as follows:

```
import * as coreJoi from "joi";
import * as joiDate from "@joi/date";
const joi = coreJoi.extend(joiDate.default(coreJoi)) as typeof coreJoi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import BaseJoi, { Extension, Root } from 'joi'
import JoiDate from '@joi/date'

const Joi = BaseJoi.extend(JoiDate as unknown as Extension) as Root
```